Is there any way of point square in elliptic curve cryptography?
From elliptic curve cryptography we can evaluate

Point addition P+ Q
Point doubling P+P

But is there any way we can determine point square?
P^2

How do I multiply two points on an elliptic curve?, and note that the point addition ( not multiplication) comes from Over the complex numbers, any elliptic curve can be realized as ℂ/Γ for some lattice Γ. In this case, addition simply comes from standard addition of complex numbers.

If you define point squaring as $xG \rightarrow x^2G$ (for some fixed point $G$), then that operation would allow you to solve the Computational Diffie-Hellman problem efficiently.  So, no, it doesn't look likely.

When we're doing point doubling then we're multiplying with 2, a vector. Multiplication with a vector is defined, multiplication with another point is not.
So this begs the question what kind of operation would be represented by squaring, as that's $P\times P$. So in general the answer is no; you'd first have to define what is meant with point multiplication.
